# Making excel search using one letter in cell

Tags: excel

So basically, I have been trying to make excel scan one column and print out the row for cells which have specific letters.

For example I have the following data in my sheet.

[image]

What is required is to be have excel search for the values which contain T and I, and then print the new rows. Kind of like separate the two into two different tables, because then so that I can do further analysis on them.

So far I have been trying to use the VLOOKUP() function, but the problem with VLOOKUP() is that excel required a proper match and not just a letter in the cell. I had tried with both FALSE and TRUE. Then instead I tried to use the =INDEX($B$4:$K$9;MATCH($A$17;$A$5:$A$9;0);COLUMN(A4)) to make it work. But that also does not work, since it also requires a full match. Also another problem which I didn't realise before is that how can excel recognise each cell, because I will have different number after the letters everytime and then so how can one make excel not repeat the same row twice?

I have used another approach where I copy the data in a separated sheet and then I simply filter out the Ts and then copy/paste the Is into another sheet and vice versa. it is time consuming and so it would be much better if I can simply copy/paste my new data and it would generate the division on its own.

any suggestions or link would be really helpful.

**UPDATE**

I had a new idea on how to approach this problem. I was thinking that is it somehow possible to have VBA code running for filtering the data. Is there a way to specify in VBA code to filter the data by "Starts With" and Make the results be printed in another cell block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks simple enough. First step is to make sure you have headers over your data and that it is in proper table format similar to my picture. Then select Data set and press CTRL+T. That should turn you data in to table object with stripes. Use the Formula =LEFT(C2,1) to take out the first letter which will be L or T.
Select the table and press ALT+D+P which will generate a pivot table based off original data set.
Drag the column with the formula I suggested over to the FILTERS area of the pivot table ID column to ROWS and all others to VALUES. Simply refresh and as new data is added you will get new pivot tables. Do not put the pivot tables on top of each other as I did that is only for the picture so you can see it. If you have too many filters to apply you can right click the helper column in the pivot table fields area to produce a slicer which is a button that helps you change the report quickly. Any other questions do ask.[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you soo much!! It is working very well. I am going to try it out now on my data set and see if it will be work out in my position. Thank you once again!! :) :)

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to select your answer as final answer. My apologies. Once again thank you :) Your method is working like magic.